# Writing to Excel with Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've searched around forums without prevail, so here I am.

I'm attempting to implement a method which writes to Excel, but every time it just corrupts the file. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public static XSSFSheet printToExcel (ArrayList<String> al, Workbook wb, XSSFSheet s, FileWriter fw) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int numOfRows = s.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfRows; i++ ) {
        XSSFRow row = s.createRow(i);
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(i);
        String text = al.get(i);
        cell.setCellValue(text);
        fw.write(text);
        fw.close();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Hopefully you all can help me. I'm mostly self-taught so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Write the workbook, not the text, to the output stream, and only once, at the end, after all of your content has been created.  [Writing a New File](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api) | [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Comment: Would you be so kind to show me an example of this utilizing my snippet? I attempted said modification but it still doesn't seem to work. I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example which I wrote in another context  but it will help you to start

```
 import org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.HyperlinkType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Hyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class WriteExcelBasic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String excelFileName = "/Users/home/Test3.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);


        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet");
 XSSFFont urlFont = wb.createFont();// changed lines
 urlFont.setFontHeight((short)(9*20));
       // urlFont.setUnderline((byte)10);
        //urlFont.setBold(true);
       urlFont.setFontName("Arial");
        urlFont.setItalic(true);
      urlFont.setColor(new XSSFColor(Color.BLUE)); // changed lines



        style.setFont(urlFont);
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);


            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);


                Hyperlink link = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
                String ss = "http://news.google.com/news/headlines?ned=us&hl=en";
                //String ss = "swasdqde";
               link.setAddress(ss);
                cell.setHyperlink(link);
                cell.setCellValue(ss);
                if(r == 1) {
                    System.out.println("In yellow");
                    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(Color.YELLOW));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("In red");
                    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(Color.RED));
                }
                cell.setCellStyle(style);


            }
        }

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            wb.write(baos);
            byte[] myByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            fos.write(myByteArray);
            fos.flush();
        }
        finally {
            wb.close();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```